# Is it possible to validate a session only from a certain path?

Tags: php, session

I have two different websites running on one domain and on one server. However, if I log on to one page, I am automatically logged on to the other page, which is located in a different folder / path.

Even if I log out, I am logged out automatically on both sides. How can I solve that problem?

I use the variable $_SESSION and to delete session_destory()

Answer (score 0):

PHP session is server dependent so if the request is coming from the same machine even if they are different domains the server sees it as the same. Your best bet would be to run them on different servers.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by assigning the session to an array when creating the session.

Comment: If it works for your use case, that great!

Comment: Yeah, but thank you!

Comment: Most welcome :)